# Empty /vagrant folder after I power off the VM

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a Vagrant VM using Virtualbox.

I have many files in my root folder which appear in `/vagrant` folder inside the VM.

When I power it off and restart it, the `/vagrant` folder is empty.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you powering the vm off and restarting?

It is vagrant who mounts that directory.

If you are doing that operations from VirtualBox directly it is not going to be mounted.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did it from VB. I did not imagine that this was the problem.